# Alignment Issue: Full Screen vs Resized

Tags: css

I took a WP theme and have customized it for my needs. I have got into a issue now with CSS.

It looks fine on full size
[image: In Full size]

However when resized or when viewed on iPad, the header is getting distorted. As you can see the RSS icon on the top right has gone past the colored header.

[image: When resized]

Any pointers in this regard would be appreciated.

Please let me know if you need some more information.

In case you need to check with Firebug/other inspector tool, here is [my site](http://www.learnqtp.com/)

Comment: While I have already got an answer, I see that my question is put on hold as off topic with reasoning "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it" I feel I have described the specific problem in detail using the 2 screenshots above. I also made a note at the bottom giving my site's URL so that anyone can check using a web inspector tool. Please let me know the issue you people felt, this will help me in future to better frame my questions for Stack Overflow standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a block overflows, it does not scale the parallel ones. Putting `div#header` `div#menu` and `div#footer` into `div#content` parallel to the container should solve the issue.

**CSS alternative way:**

Add floated fixing to the container and all childs, in this case:

```
#top-overlay, #header, #menu, #content, #footer {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: A gray bottom has come up below the navigation menu. While the height of menu still is 72 px, earlier the box was transparent. I know I can set the height to some other value to remove the bottom but am wondering what and why the CSS change you suggested above created that gray bottom.

Comment: @AnkurJain I missed 1 block there. You have to apply the changes to `#footer` aswell as it is a child aswell. What you see there as grey box is basically the footer background, since it goes up to the top because everything else is floating.
Edited the answer to the correct one.